# Rails precompiled asset application.js/css not referenced in the layout file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Using Rails 3.2.13 I am able to precompile assets but the precompiled and fingerprinted assets are not referenced in the layout file. I am using Passenger Phusion. View source of the application shows

```
 <script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Expected is**

```
 <script src="/assets/application-e5ac9ae789236e9d09602326bf283bb2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> Any idea what is missing?

application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

application.rb

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
```

production.rb

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
  #devise
end
```

Comment: Please show what your layout file contains. Does it contain `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`??

Comment: @SankalpSingha it does have it except the data-turbolinks-track

Comment: Is your passenger really running as production environment? Did you define RailsEnv in httpd.conf?